# character string that represents date in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How do I return a character string that represents the specified datepart of the specified date using PostgreSQL?

**Note**: In SQL Server we use the following syntax.

**Example**: (Using SQL Server)

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW,'2014-05-22'); /*For Weekday */
```

Comment: Functun reference should clear it up http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @Jester: please don't link to totally outdated versions. You can use `current` instead of the version number to create a link to the current version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) the `to_char()` function can be used for this:

```
select to_char(DATE '2014-05-22', 'Day');
```

returns `Thursday`

Answer (score 1):

```
date_part(text, timestamp)
```

Example for day of the week:

```
select date_part('dow', timestamp '2014-05-22 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thank you. But here I need to show "Thursday". How can do that?